# Java in scanner, input mismatch exception

Tags: java, sockets

I am working on java messaging service (Twitter style) in cmd.

I have a message client, where I capture user command / argument.

First argument and command for example could be "login pete" and that would work.

However typing "open mike" afterwards to open mike's channel gives me input mismatch exception.

Code

```
public class MessageClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        /*
         * if (args.length != 2) { System.err.println(
         * "Usage: java EchoClient <host name> <port number>"); System.exit(1); }
         */

        /*
         * String hostName = args[0]; int portNumber = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
         */
        String hostName = "localhost";
        int portNumber = 12345;

        try (
            Socket messageSocket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);
            PrintWriter out =
                new PrintWriter(messageSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            Scanner in = new Scanner(messageSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader stdIn =
                new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        ) {

            String userInput;
            while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
                out.println(userInput);
                // Read number of response lines (and skip newline character).
                int n = in.nextInt(); // Input mismatch happens here

                in.nextLine();
                // Read and print each response line.
                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                    System.out.println(in.nextLine());


            }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host " + hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to " +
                hostName);
            System.exit(1);
        }
        finally {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you want `in.nextLine()` instead of `in.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
int n = in.nextInt(); // Input mismatch happens here
in.nextLine();
```

with

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) for a detailed discussion.

**[Update]**

If you are not comfortable with using the debugger, you can check the value captured by `in.nextLine()` as follows:

```
String n = in.nextLine();
System.out.println(n);
int n = Integer.parseInt(n);
```

This will give you an idea where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Arvind, thanks for replying. I have tried this, and issue still persists.

Comment: @Jaro - I've posted an update. Check if that helps.